# Why do I get an error about the extension.list.module service non existing?

Tags: 8, commerce

I installed Drupal 8.5.6 and Drupal Commerce with Composer. They installed fine, but after I cleared the cache, I got this exception in a WSOD.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: "You have requested a non-existent service "extension.list.module"." at C:\wamp\www\drupal-8.5.6\core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php line 151

I searched for *extension.list.module* and I found this.

```
function system_rebuild_module_data() {
  return \Drupal::service('extension.list.module')->reset()->getList();
}
```

What did I do wrong to cause this problem?
What is my next step to solve this dilemma?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you sure you installed Drupal 8.5.6? Because the code you are showing is used from Drupal 8.6.0.

Comment: As I thrash my way through the weeds, I believe I must have used composer inappropriately and upgraded drupal core  rather than updated the console and commerce.   I'll do more thorough research on the lock and json files.  Thank you for the observation.  I'll look in a different direction for my problem and report back.

Comment: The problem is the nut sitting between the chair and the keyboard - me.  My drupal was not originally built with composer ergo the code base is not in the subdirectory /web.  My composer command to install drupal/commerce was following a script from online and it was overly broad.  Drupal commerce was installed in the /web subdirectory.  Searching back through my composer listings I found I had invoked a global update command with -dev  on it.  My solution is to save my theme/module/htaccess/site code: blow away the code base: reinstall drupal with composer and begin my journey again.  JW

Comment: We all did silly mistakes. You have been able to understand what was wrong, and that is positive. Since you are talking of finding the code base in /web, I guess you used drupal-composer/drupal-project as composer template to install Drupal. When you are allowed to add an answer, you could write it.

Answer (score 0):

When Drupal loads some 'foo.bar' service (e.g. `\Drupal::service('extension.list.module')`), it expects this service to be defined in one of the `somemodule/somemodule.services.yml` files. For example:

```
services:
  extension.list.module:
    class: Drupal\somewhere\SomeService
```

This particular service (`extension.list.module`) is defined in `core/core.services.yml`

```
  extension.list.module:
    class: Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleExtensionList
```

This should be available by default, so either the Drupal core files are missing or your lost some integrity of your data in your database. Try rebuilding cache (e.g. `drush cache:rebuild`), if it fails, manually clear all `cache_*` tables (especially `cache_bootstrap`). Otherwise restore your database from the backup.